# Origin of a term in an inequality.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am reading about Calculus where in my book it is explaining the method of exhaustion using modern algebraic notation with a parabola in the first quadrant, it took the sum of areas of all the rectangles within the parabola and the sum of areas of all the rectangles that cross the parabola and it gave the inequality,

$1^2+2^2+3^2.....(n-1)^2 < \frac{n^3}{3} < 1^2+2^2+3^2+......n^2$

I don't understand from where did they get the $\frac{n^3}{3}$ ?
I need assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that

**Fact**. For any $n>1$ we have
$$1^2+2^2+\cdots +n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Then we have

\begin{align*}
1^2+2^2+\cdots +(n-1)^2&=\frac{(n-1)((n-1)+1)(2(n-1)+1)}{6}\\
&=\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}\\
&<\frac{n\cdot n\cdot 2n}{6}\\
&=\frac{n^3}{3}\\
&=\frac{n\cdot n\cdot 2n}{6}\\
&<\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
&=1^2+2^2+\cdots +n^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: @M.Logic- Sorry for late response I just finally understood this thing today. Thanks, appreciate it man.